# How to swipe and move a UIViewController

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uigesturerecognizer, swipe

I am trying to implement swiping a `UIViewController`'s view up and down. This would be similar to Facebook Paper (swiping down to reveal search, post and other controls), or any other app that gives the user full control of moving the view with their finger.

Does anyone know how to do this efficiently?

Comment: You want to move the `ViewController` or you want to move the view of a `ViewController` ?

Comment: Put your viewControllers (you'll have more than one, because you need something to scroll to) in a UIScroll view, and set the location and content sizes to make them one above the other.

Comment: Well, I assume you have to move the view of the UIViewController. I  Whatever moves the view out of the way and reveals a new view underneath is what I want.

Comment: @OwenHartnett that does not give me the visual effect I want. Doing it that way makes it feel/appear that the view you are swiping to is above the current view, not behind it. If you have used Sparrow (swipe to reveal sidebar navigation) or Facebook Paper (swipe down to reveal extra controls) you will see what I am talking about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up finding that menus like [this one](https://github.com/mutualmobile/MMDrawerController) are what I am looking for.

Though, they aren't recommended by Apple. See [WWDC 2014 Videos](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2014/), Designing Intuitive User Experiences.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to manage your individual view controllers with a [`UIPageViewController`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIPageViewControllerClassReferenceClassRef/UIPageViewControllerClassReference.html), described this way on the class reference page:

> A page view controller lets the user navigate between pages of
>   content, where each page is managed by its own view controller object.
>   Navigation can be controlled programmatically by your app or directly
>   by the user using gestures. When navigating from page to page, the
>   page view controller uses the transition that you specify to animate
>   the change.

You can specify `UIPageViewControllerNavigationOrientationVertical` as the orientation if you want the pages to move vertically, and you can also specify the gestures and animations used to transition from one view controller to the next.

Comment: I'm not sure that is what I am looking for. If you have use Sparrow or Facebook Paper, or any app that has a swipe to reveal some navigation, you will notice that the view being revealed is stationary. With a UIPageViewController the behavior is more like a UIScrollView, where all views are moving in and out rather than one view moving and revealing a stationary view underneath it.